# Is it possible to get acf custom option value based on one of its other value?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have color settings as acf options page set as follows.
Color Settings:
Field Type : Repeater
Fields: color name and color value(e.g. orange => #FC7F34, blue => #14B1E7)

I am using this settings in my other custom fields as radio button.So when user choose button color it's saved as hex code(#FC7F34).
Now in front end I want both that color name and color value. I have tried below option but as we have multiple buttons I think this will effect the load time.

```
$data['colors'] = get_field( 'color_fields', 'option' );
foreach($data['colors'] as $color) {
    $data[$color['color_value']] = $color['color_name'];
}
```

Result:

```
[#FC7F34] => Orange
[#14B1E7] => Blue
[#007DC5] => Dark Blue
```

Is there any other effective way to show Orange when we have #FC7F34 chosen as button color.
Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible using if else condition otherwise not possible because if you find on google orange code hex code then it showing different . now it's only possible from if condition .
    if your color code is fix then one solution

```
if($data[$color['color_value']]=='#FC7F34') { echo 'orange';}
```